# I am having an issue to handle power button in my android game in canvas

Tags: android

The Game is running perfectly.
But when the power button is pressed while playing, it gets stuck.Thread keeps on running as the game screen is on but my update method is not working.
I would have to press home key button, unlock phone and resume my game, then it runs perfectly.

Can anybody help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.. Thank You all

I was doing this in onPause() method

```
if (_thread != null) 
{
   _thread.setRunning(false);
}
```

and onResume() method

i was doing this _thread.setRunning(true)

i just commented setRunning(false) in onPause Method, Now it is working fine.